# is there a way to pass extra arguments on the on_event function in EventHubConsumerClient (azure-sdk-for-python)

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

this example a simple from azure-sdk-for-python for Azure Event Hubs for a consumer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"""
An example to show receiving events from an Event Hub with checkpoint store asynchronously.
In the `receive` method of `EventHubConsumerClient`:
If no partition id is specified, the checkpoint_store are used for load-balance and checkpoint.
If partition id is specified, the checkpoint_store can only be used for checkpoint.
"""

import asyncio
import os
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR"]
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_CONN_STR"]
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = "your-blob-container-name"  # Please make sure the blob container resource exists.


async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # Put your code here.
    print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)


async def receive(client):
    """
    Without specifying partition_id, the receive will try to receive events from all partitions and if provided with
    a checkpoint store, the client will load-balance partition assignment with other EventHubConsumerClient instances
    which also try to receive events from all partitions and use the same storage resource.
    """
    await client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
    # With specified partition_id, load-balance will be disabled, for example:
    # await client.receive(on_event=on_event, partition_id='0'))


async def main():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,  # For load-balancing and checkpoint. Leave None for no load-balancing.
    )
    async with client:
        await receive(client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Is there a way to pass a extra argument in the on_event function.
For example, in this consumer i receive messages from a producer and let`s say i need to insert some data in a database and i need to pass an open database connection. How would i go about doing something like that?

All the examples from the [repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples) are the same way,on_event has these 2 parameters, which frankly i do not understand where they come from.

thanks

Comment: @krishg's statement is correct, and I'd encourage moving that to an answer so that it can be accepted.   As mentioned, the processor invokes the `on_event` handler and requires that specific signature to do so.

Answer (score 2):

`on_event(partition_context, event)` is the callback method which is meant to be passed to `client.receive` method to tell it "Handle the event *this* way when you receive it". So obviously `on_event` has to follow a fixed method 'signature' for the client receiver to be able to call the callback on receiving event. Even if it were possible to pass additional argument to `on_event`, it would be useless to you anyway since you are not calling that method.

Rather suggest you do it this way. Declare a field outside the `on_event` method, initialize it from some declaring method and access it inside `on_event` like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"""
An example to show receiving events from an Event Hub with checkpoint store asynchronously.
In the `receive` method of `EventHubConsumerClient`:
If no partition id is specified, the checkpoint_store are used for load-balance and checkpoint.
If partition id is specified, the checkpoint_store can only be used for checkpoint.
"""

import asyncio
import os
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR"]
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_CONN_STR"]
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = "your-blob-container-name"  # Please make sure the blob container resource exists.

MY_DATABASE_CONNECTION = None

async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # Put your code here.
 
    # Use MY_DATABASE_CONNECTION as needed
    
    print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)


async def receive(client):
    """
    Without specifying partition_id, the receive will try to receive events from all partitions and if provided with
    a checkpoint store, the client will load-balance partition assignment with other EventHubConsumerClient instances
    which also try to receive events from all partitions and use the same storage resource.
    """
    MY_DATABASE_CONNECTION = <initilize it>

    await client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
    # With specified partition_id, load-balance will be disabled, for example:
    # await client.receive(on_event=on_event, partition_id='0'))


async def main():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,  # For load-balancing and checkpoint. Leave None for no load-balancing.
    )
    async with client:
        await receive(client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```